# Css support for safari browser in mobile devices

Tags: php, html, css, mobile-safari

I used the below coding for support only safari browser.

```
if(strtolower($browser->browser) == 'safari') {
    echo '<link href="<long_path>/safari.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
}
```

Its working fine only for safari in desktop.but its not working for mobile safari browser.

Comment: Do we guess what the `$browser` objects consists of?

Comment: it might work better for you in the long run to use client side feature detection instead of browser sniffing to include appropriate style information. look at [modernizr](http://modernizr.com) as a good tool to help with this.

Comment: $browser=get_browser_local();

Answer (score 0):

Here you go use demo.mobiledetect.net to test if it works:

[CLICK HERE](http://demo.mobiledetect.net)

Comment: Chrome also has `" AppleWebkit"` in its user agent string.

Comment: I need to use css for safari mobile version only..if i use webkit, its apply for chrome also..

Comment: @manoranjani.a What about this? http://help.campaignmonitor.com/topic.aspx?t=164 this should help. Please + if it help'd.

Comment: @Tredged ,I used the media query..its not applied for mobile version.. its applied only for desktop safari browser only.

Comment: @manoranjani.a Then just use this: http://mobiledetect.net/ works like a charm just tested it for myself.